# Very UGLY font rendering in java apps

Tags: 15.04, java, fonts

Does anybody in here knows how to fix these fugly fonts? 
I've got installed java openjdk 8 and im running on ubuntu 15.04.
I tried installing java oracle jdk 8 but it didn't help, then i deleted it and installed openjdk 7, rebooted my pc, it didn't help then i installed openjdk 8, rebooted pc...same thing again.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nbzs3qW.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

*Adapted from my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636666/ugly-non-anti-aliased-fonts-in-java-swing-applications).*

Adding this line:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
```

to `/etc/environment` should fix this issue.

If you can't edit your `/etc/environment` for some reason or it doesn't work then you can try running this command instead in a terminal and then launching the app (from the same terminal):

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
```

This fix works as of Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenJDK 8u151 (haven't checked with Oracle JDK or Java 9) on the jEdit text-editor and other Java Swing applications.

Working example (jEdit):
[image]

**Note**: Some fonts and AA settings complicate the problem. In jEdit, I use the default Java fonts ("Dialog" as it's called) for everything. You can probably use a different font for the Text-Area but Dialog is the best for buttons, etc. The best Text-Area AA setting I've found is *standard* but your mileage may vary.

Comment: This doesn't help with running DecoderPro 4.14 under Java 11.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score -1):

You have to change default font in windows that you provide above.
For IDE I love to use Hack, or Inconsolata
Those fonts are located in here https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Please see readme.md for installing

Comment: Doesn't help mate :/